# How to connect to a remote system using ftp command?

Tags: ftp

I have to transfer files from machine to another(both windows platform) and for that purpose i am trying out with ftp commands. So, i am opening command prompt and typing the following:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> ftp
ftp> open sample.com
ftp> username
```

Now when i enter username it throws me error as "Not connected".I am not getting what am i doing wrong. The user name is absolutely correct.Please suggest how do i connect to remote system using ftp commands.

Comment: Maybe this should be in SuperUser instead of Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the "open" command failed and you are not really connected to the ftp server.

Here is what a good connection looks like:

```
C:\>ftp
ftp> open ftp.microsoft.com
Connected to ftp.microsoft.akadns.net.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
User (ftp.microsoft.akadns.net:(none)): anonymous
331 Anonymous access allowed, send identity (e-mail name) as password.
Password:
230-Welcome to FTP.MICROSOFT.COM. Also visit http://www.microsoft.com/downloads.
230 User logged in.
ftp>
```

Here the username is "anonymous" and I provided that at the "User" prompt.

You can do this in another way:

```
C:\>ftp
ftp> open ftp.microsoft.com
Connected to ftp.microsoft.akadns.net.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
User (ftp.microsoft.akadns.net:(none)):
501 Invalid number of parameters.
Login failed.
ftp> user anonymous
331 Anonymous access allowed, send identity (e-mail name) as password.
Password:
230-Welcome to FTP.MICROSOFT.COM. Also visit http://www.microsoft.com/downloads.
230 User logged in.
ftp>
```

Here I did not enter the username but used the "user" command provided by the ftp client to provide the username "anonymous"

None of these look like what you are experiencing. Could this be because you have removed some of the information in the interest of confidentiality? If so, that makes it difficult to help.

Also, it would help to read up on some help on using FTP command.

Here is one I found off google that I think would walk you through FTP commands: [FTP and SFTP Beginners Guide with 10 Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/ftp-sftp-tutorial/)